# How to imlement print on Android using Cordova?

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to implement print functionality in Android app, I'm using AngularJS. I have tried the below code, but it works only on browser, it doesn't work on Android.

**AngularJS:**

```
$scope.print = function (divName) {
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write($('#' + divName).html());
    w.print();
    w.close();
}
```

**Html:**

```
<img ng-click="print('print');" class="card-img-top image-responsive" src="./plugins/images/print.png" alt="Card image cap">


<div id="print" style="display:none;">
    <style>
        @page {
            size: auto;
            margin: 7mm;
        }

        @media all {
            .page-break {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media print {
            .page-break {
                display: block;
                page-break-before: always;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I have tried the solution provided by @VicJordan, But it gives the below error.

> ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at ChildScope.$scope.print
>
> (MyJs.js:37) at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15500),
>
> :4:149) at callback (angular.js:27285) at ChildScope.$eval
>
> (angular.js:18372) at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18472) at
>
> HTMLImageElement. (angular.js:27290) at
>
> HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3) at
>
> HTMLImageElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "helloworld",
    "displayName": "HelloCordova",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "^1.0.7",
        "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.7.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-printer": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Update2**

**MyJS.js**

```
app.controller('ReciepieController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$state', '$window', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $state, $window, $uibModal) {

    $("#header").show();

    $rootScope.back = true;
    $rootScope.enableback = true;

    $scope.toggleText = "See More...";

    $scope.toggle = 0;

    $scope.print = function (divName) {
        console.log('2222222222222222222');
        //Enter the page location.
        var page = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html', function () {
            alert('printing finished or canceled')
        });
    }

    $scope.change = function () {
        if ($scope.toggle == 0) {
            $scope.toggleText = "See Less...";
            $scope.toggle = 1;
        }
        else if ($scope.toggle == 1) {
            $scope.toggleText = "See More...";
            $scope.toggle = 0;
        }
    }
    var recipe = null;
    var categorylist = [];

    $scope.GetRecipe = function (paginate) {

        if (paginate == "next") {
            if ($rootScope.RecipeIndex < categorylist.length - 1) {
                $rootScope.RecipeIndex = $rootScope.RecipeIndex + 1;
                $scope.IsNext = true;
                $scope.IsPrevious = true;
                if ($rootScope.RecipeIndex == categorylist.length - 1) { $scope.IsNext = false; }
            }
        }
        else if (paginate == "previous") {
            if ($rootScope.RecipeIndex < $rootScope.RecipeList.length) {
                $rootScope.RecipeIndex = $rootScope.RecipeIndex - 1;
                $scope.IsNext = true;
                $scope.IsPrevious = true;
            }
        }
        if ($rootScope.RecipeIndex == -1) {
            $rootScope.RecipeIndex = 0;
        }
        if ($rootScope.RecipeIndex == 0 || $rootScope.RecipeIndex == -1) { $scope.IsPrevious = false; }
        recipe = categorylist[$rootScope.RecipeIndex];
        $scope.Ingredient = recipe.recipeIngredients.split('\n');
        $scope.Method = recipe.recipeMethod.split('\n');
        $scope.Image = recipe.imageName;
        $scope.Name = recipe.recipeTitle;
        $scope.Description = recipe.recipeDescription;
        $scope.Prep = recipe.preparationTime;
        $scope.Cook = recipe.cookingTime;
        $scope.Serves = recipe.servings;
        $scope.QrCode = recipe.QrCode;
        $rootScope.IsBack = false;
        $rootScope.IsTitle = false;
    }

    $scope.share = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'QrCode.html',
            controller: 'ReciepieController',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            size: 'sm',
            backdrop: 'static', /*  this prevent user interaction with the background  */
            keyboard: false
        });
    }

    function NextRecipe() {
        alert();
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same issue. 
Try to do it using [cordova-plugin-printer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer) plugin. It will solve your problem. From your code it looks you want to print `div` by `id`. Below are various usage of above plugin:

Print the whole HTML page:

```
var page = location.href;

cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html');
```

Print the content from one part of the page:

```
var page = document.getElementById('legal-notice');

cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html');
```

Print some custom content:

```
var page = '<h1>Hello Document</h1>';

cordova.plugins.printer.print(page, 'Document.html');
```

For more options, check out the documentation : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer#usage

Comment: @viveknuna what’s **it’s**? check your decencies etc. this is very vague error.

Comment: @viveknuna I am not sure how and where are you running this code? I tried with very simple code and its working as expected. Here are steps of my app, 1. Created HelloWorld app from here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html 2. Installed **cordova-plugin-printer** as per documentation here https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer#installation 3. Added **Print the whole HTML page:** code from Examples in `onDeviceReady` function because I don't have separate js file and that's it. It is working. Issue is with your `MyJs.js` file.

Comment: I can guess, you have not added `cordova` as dependency in your `angular.module`. But this plugin works perfectly fine.

Comment: For your information, here I created the video of working demo and code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=115bW2_brZriIHKBr54aVq2AnyfDhiPAS

Comment: @viveknuna did you check my comments? Is it working now?

Comment: yes I saw your comment, but couldn’t try, I’ll try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Where should I add `cordova` as a dependency in my  `angular.module`?

Comment: You want me to help you which is not even in your requirement and which is very basic but you don’t have courtesy even to upvote my answer. Sorry to say I don’t have any more motivation to help you.

Comment: Hey @VicJordan, please don't mind it. I was about to upvote and as well as accept your answer if I would have got my solution.  I always upvote and accept the answer. I have upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in javascript

```js
var dowloadurl  = "/.../sample.pdf" // Here your file location
window.cordova.plugins.FileOpener.openFile(
   dowloadurl,
   onSuccessFileOpen,
   onErrorFileOpen
);
    
var onSuccessFileOpen = function (data) {
    alert('onSuccessFileOpen');
};

function onErrorFileOpen(err) {
    alert('message: ' + err);
}
```