# Can't print the entire page when I have a scrollable content with many items in IONIC3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I used Cordova Print Plugin to print a table that has scrollable content.
I want to print that page from a print button in an Android device.
But when I do that, I am getting the content of only one page.

The next pages are not showing.

Kindly help me.

I already tried adding media queries.

Incoming Report.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{'Incoming Report' | translate}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
<ion-content>

    <ion-row class="button-print">
        <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6 style="text-align: center;"> <button ion-button color='danger' (click)="generatePDF()">Print Report</button></ion-col>  
         <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
         </ion-row>

        <div> ......Here is my content</div>
  </ion-content>
```

Generatepdf Function

```
generatePDF(){

  cordova.plugins.printer.print();


}
```

IncomingReport.scss

```
@media print{
                ion-header{ display: none !important; }  
                .button-print{ display: none !important; }



                body, .app-root, .split-pane, .ion-page, ion-app, ion-nav { contain: none; }
                body, ion-nav{ overflow: initial; }
                body{ position: static; }

                ion-content{ overflow-y: visible !important; 

                    position: relative; }
              }
```

Comment: See if this Helps <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462467/how-to-imlement-print-on-android-using-cordova>

Comment: I already tried that.`var page = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');cordova.plugins.printer.print(page);`